# Read numbers from <pre>

Tags: javascript, html, pre

I am trying to calculate certain numbers in an array of numbers in a pre tag. Such as count how many of the numbers are 7 or higher.
For example, I have this

```
    <pre class="data">2 7 3 1 2
    6   6   2   5   3
    8   2   5   9   9
    5   10  5   6   10
    2   10  3   </pre>
```

I've figured out how to get to the numbers in a general way:

```
    document.getElementsByTagName ('PRE')[0].firstChild.data = document.getElementsByTagName ('PRE')[0].firstChild.data.replace (/\t+$/, '')
```

But I do not know how to get at the individual numbers. Is it an array? Or a list of numbers that I need to parse by space?

I've looked at this thread: [Using <pre> tag to display data in columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589693/using-pre-tag-to-display-data-in-columns) and tried to use a for loop grabbing $entry[i], but I am not able to read individual numbers.

Comment: It will be a string that you have to split by line break, then by space

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The content of the pre tag is just text.  In order to access the numbers, you have to parse the text.  I'm assuming you just need the list of numbers, and there is no significance to the columns.

If this is true, what you need to do is split the text on whitespace, and then process each item:

```
var number_string = document.getElementsByTagName ('PRE')[0].firstChild.data;

var numbers = number_string.split(/[\s]+/);
var a_number;

for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
    a_number = parseInt(numbers[i]);  // assuming the numbers are whole numbers.
}
```

Note that numbers[i] is actually a string representation of the number, so you need to use  parseInt(numbers[i]) to get the real number. (or parseFloat(numbers[i]) if they are not whole numbers)

Hope that's helpful.

Jay

Comment: I see `for` loops when the `Array.prototype.map` function could be used here and it makes me cry a little.

Comment: I understand, but for loops are a lot more familiar to folks than map and it's brethren.  I would not expect someone unfamiliar with split & regular expressions to be quite ready to understand functional programming. ;-)

Comment: `\s` gives you `\n` and `\t` for free. Also, `a_number` is going to be overwritten each time through the loop.

Comment: True enough.  Leftover from tinkering with the regexp, fixed.

Comment: @JayK, perhaps. But just because it is functional(ish) doesn't mean it isn't something worth learning. I take the philosophy that it's better to lead by example and not attempt to "dumb things down" only to perpetuate complexity. Anyway that's my opinion and I'm *not* disagreeing with you.

Comment: I'm not aware of any DOM property named `data`--what is that supposed to be? Did you test this? Also, the square brackets in `[\s]` are redundant. Your call to `split` will return empty elements if the content starts or ends with whitespace, which `parseInt` will then turn into a `NaN`. Your use of `parseInt` will also turn invalid entries like "1b" into the number 1, rather than reporting an error. You overwrite `a_number` each time through the loop, leaving you with just the last one. All in all, not a very convincing "accepted" answer.

Comment: I'd wager the reason it's the accepted answer is that it contains an explanation that helps the OP understand what he needs to do.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you a 2-dimensional array:

```
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].textContent;

str                                 // take the string and
    .split('\n')                    // break it into an array of lines;
    .map(function(line) {           // then transform each line by
        return line                 // taking the line,
            .trim()                 // removing leading and trailing spaces,
            .split(/\s+/)           // and breaking it into an array at whitespace,
            .map(Number);           // with each piece cast to a number.
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lwkw4ee4/

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {  // just in case of an old browser
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

var str = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML.trim();
var data = str.split(/\s+/);
alert(data);
```

data will be an 1D array of numbers (to be accurate - strings with numbers, but it does not matter - it is easy to cast).

Comment: `\s` includes `\t` and `\n` (and `\f` while you're at it). Also, the regexp fed to split doesn't really need a `g` flag.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanx.. I'm coding on too many languages to remember the small nuances )

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/mepulu/2/edit

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('data')[0].innerHTML; // Text
var values = text.split(/\s+/); // Array of strings
var numbers = values.map(function(num) {
  return parseInt(num, 10);
});
numbers; // Array of integers
```